# PHP Update +1 adding random numbers

Tags: php, sql-update, adsense

I have a news website with a very simple php script to tally up the number of readers for each article.  When I run the site on my localhost, the number adds up by one each time I visit the article page, however when I run it on the live site, sometimes the read count goes up by 4-6 each time I visit and I can't understand why.

Here is the php code:

```
$update_views_sql = "UPDATE article SET views = views +1 WHERE id = '$post_id'";
$update_views_res = mysqli_query($con, $update_views_sql);
```

The only thing different between the local & live site is the activation of Adsense adverts - Could they be the problem or is there another reason?

Comment: May be Bots accessing your site (It could be any bot)?

Comment: Are you using url rewriting and if yes, is that exactly the same on both servers?

Comment: @AncientGeek That could be one reason over a period of time, but this instant, as in when I add a post and view it, the count is already at 6

Comment: @jeroen No I'm not using any rewriting

Comment: Basically the query as shown is correct and will only increment by 1 each time it is called. Try checking if it is included more than once (try `echo "something";` right after it to check) .

Comment: Compare the count to your web server logs.